# Is there any way to add lists to dictionaries? Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm relatively new to programming and completely new to this website, so I'll just get into the question I've been trying to figure out the answer to for the last hour.

I want to add items to two lists and then put those lists into a dictionary to store and eventually output.

I've come up with two different solutions but neither of them work:

Using the collections module:

```
import collections
Cnum = 5
print("We will now be asking you to enter the names and age of the individual people coming. ")
details = {}
count = 0
Cnam = []
Cage = []
while count < Cnum:
    Cnam.append( raw_input('Please enter the name of a citizen: '))
    Cage.append(int(raw_input('Please enter the age of this citizen: ')))
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    d[Cname].append(Cage)
    count = count + 1
print details
```

And without:

```
Cnum = 5
details = {}
count = 0
Cnam = []
Cage = []
while count < Cnum
    Cnam.append(raw_input('Please enter the name of a citizen: '))
    Cage.append(int(raw_input('Please enter the age of this citizen: ')))
    details[Cnam] = Cage
    count = count + 1
print details
```

Any help would really be appreciated. If it's not possible to add lists to dictionaries, any alternative ideas would also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually want the `Cnam` and `Cage` lists? Or do you just want a simple dictionary with each name being a key and the age as the value associated with that key?

Comment: BTW, you have a couple of typos in your code blocks: `d` instead of `details` in the 1st one, and a missing `:` at the end of the `while` statement in the 2nd one.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I just want the user to input the name and age of different people, and then store it in a dictionary.

Comment: In that case, please see the last code block in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually want the `Cnam` and `Cage` lists, the simple way is to create the lists and then pass them to the `dict` constructor using the built-in `zip` function.

```
Cnum = 5
Cnam = []
Cage = []
for count in range(Cnum):
    Cnam.append(raw_input('Please enter the name of a citizen: '))
    Cage.append(int(raw_input('Please enter the age of this citizen: ')))

print Cnam
print Cage
details = dict(zip(Cnam, Cage))
print details
```

**test**

```
Please enter the name of a citizen: a
Please enter the age of this citizen: 1
Please enter the name of a citizen: b
Please enter the age of this citizen: 2
Please enter the name of a citizen: c
Please enter the age of this citizen: 3
Please enter the name of a citizen: d
Please enter the age of this citizen: 4
Please enter the name of a citizen: e
Please enter the age of this citizen: 5
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
```

---

If you don't need those lists, we can make the code simpler:

```
Cnum = 5
details = {}
for count in range(Cnum):
    Cnam = raw_input('Please enter the name of a citizen: ')
    Cage = int(raw_input('Please enter the age of this citizen: '))
    details[Cnam] = Cage
print details
```

Comment: I needed the lists, so thanks so much. You're really a life saver! Haha. If I had enough reputation for my up votes to make a difference, I would do it! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I see it that you trying to set as dictionary's key unhashable type 'list'. You cannot do this.
Try to use tuple instead:

```
details[tuple(Cnam)] = Cage
```

So you can do this:

```
Cnum = 5
details1 = {}
details2 = {}
count = 0
Cnam = []
Cage = []
while count < Cnum:
    name = raw_input('Please enter the name of a citizen: ')
    Cnam.append(name)
    age = int(raw_input('Please enter the age of this citizen: '))
    Cage.append(age)
    details1[name] = age
    count = count + 1
details2[tuple(Cnam)] = Cage
print('Cnam: {}'.format(Cnam))
print('Cage: {}'.format(Cage))
print('details1: {}'.format(details1))
print('details2: {}'.format(details2))
```

Output:

```
Cnam: ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't']
Cage: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
details1: {'q': 1, 'r': 4, 'e': 3, 't': 5, 'w': 2}
details2: {('q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't'): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: I tried this but it says "ValueError: zero length field name in formal"